# Generate different random coordinates

Tags: c++, random, coordinates

So i have this square of '*' made with `vector<string>`. Now i need to generate six numbers that represent different coordinates from 1 to N*N(this is the area of the square) so I can alter them. What I have so far is this

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int N = 4, x, y;
    srand(time(NULL));
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            //generate 6 random coordinates
            int rnd = rand() % (N*N-1) + 2;

            if(rnd <= N){
                x = rnd;
                y = 0;
            }
            else{ 
                if((x = (rnd % N) - 1) < 0){
                x = rnd / N - 1;
                y = x;
                }
                else y = rnd / N;
            }

            std::cout << "rnd: " << rnd << " x:" << x << " y:" << y << "\n\n";
        }

}
```

But i keep getting same coordinates. Is my code flawed or i need to add something?

Comment: [here](http://ideone.com/XADzCk) it works (does something apparently pseudorandom)...

Comment: `srand` will only change the value a little bit every second, so if you run this code twice in short succession, I expect you do indeed get same/similar results. This has to do with how "random seeds" work - your seed is a only going from 111318789 to 111318790 the next second, it's not like it scrambles every bit in the number. You could try using a "get nano second time", or you could wait a little longer between runs...

Comment: @0d0a it generates 7 three times

Comment: @MatsPetersson how can I get nano second time, didn't find anything on google

Comment: @user2202368 Why is generating 7 three times a problem? You are aware that random number generators can return the same number more than once?

Comment: @interjay how do i avoid returning the same number

Comment: @user2202368 This is an interesting question. You must post it separately, in order not to hijack this post (and also because this question is closed, and it's impossible to add a new answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing some weird things to get `x` and `y`. It's much simpler than what you've got:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        // the square is N x N, so you want two numbers from 0 to N-1

        int x = rand() % N;
        int y = rand() % N;

        std::cout << "x:" << x << " y:" << y << "\n\n";
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        int rnd = rand() % (N*N);
        int x = rnd % N;
        int y = rnd / N;

        std::cout << "rnd: " << rnd << " x:" << x << " y:" << y << "\n\n";
    }
```

Of course using `%` to get random numbers this way is a terrible idea, and common implementations of `rand()` just happen to have really terrible characteristics when combining multiple values into coordinates into a multi-dimensional space: Patterns are [likely to emerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#mediaviewer/File:Lcg_3d.gif).

Instead you need to take care when manipulating random values from one range into the desired range. Fortunately somebody has already don't the math for you and you can make use of that through the `<random>` library.

```
#include <random>

std::mt19937 eng; // object which produces random bits

std::random_device r;
std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
eng.seed(seed); // seed the bit generator, replaces srand()

std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, N-1); // encapsulates the correct method of turning
                                              // random bits into random numbers in the range
                                              // [0, N)
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  int x = dist(eng); // the distribution internally used the engine like rand()
  int y = dist(eng);

  std::cout << "x:" << x << " y:" << y << "\n\n";
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
std::random_device r;
std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
std::mt19937 eng(seed);

std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, N*N - 1);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  int rnd = dist(eng);
  int x = rnd % N; // used of % here is just fine
  int y = rnd / N;

  std::cout << "rnd: " << rnd << " x:" << x << " y:" << y << "\n\n";
}
```

Here's a complete program which produces a square of '*' in a `vector<string>`, generates coordinates and marks those coordinates in the square:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e024212ebc951f92

The results look like:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
x:0 y:7

x:0 y:2

x:6 y:8

x:5 y:0

x:4 y:7

x:0 y:2

***** ****
**********
 *********
**********
**********
**********
**********
 *** *****
****** ***
**********
```

Comment: saved me quite some trouble, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Other Answer(s) discuss the problem caused by `srand(time(NULL))`

Well,

this is assured to work for Generation of Random numbers, Regardless of time interval between two calls made.

You can use something like

```
int Min, Max;
random_device rd;   // non-deterministic generator
mt19937 gen(rd());  // to seed mersenne twister.
uniform_int_distribution<> dist(Min,Max); // distribute results between Min and Max inclusive.'
```

and then Generate Number and assign it using

```
int Rand=dist(gen);
```

don't forget to include

```
<random>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get different results each time I run this. Note, though, than time(NULL) only changes once a second, so running this twice within the same chronological second will produce the same random seed.

However, there are a number of other problems with your code. Your math is wrong.

1)

```
int rnd = rand() % (N*N-1) + 2;
```

This will always produce a result of at least 2, so you will never get the result of 1, which the rest of the code, it seems, intent to reference the top-left corner of your grid. So, right off the bat, your random formula is skewed.

2)

You have N*N coordinates in your grid.

```
rand() % *value*
```

The remainder of a division by "value" (presuming that value is positive) always produces a result between 0 and (value-1), inclusive. After all:

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
```

So:

```
rand() % (N*N-1)
```

This will always produce a result between 0 and N*N-2. So, if N is 4, N*N-1 is 15, and this will always be a result between 0 and 14, inclusive, or only 15 possible values for the random coordinate, while you really have 16 different coordinates in your grid.

Conclusion:

The overall problem with your approach stems from a disconnect between a human being's natural inclination to number things starting with 1, then 2, and so on; while dealing with computer code and algorithm, it is more natural to number things starting with 0, rather than 1.

When that happens, your entire random coordinate generation becomes laughably simple:

```
int rnd = rand() % (N*N);

int x= rnd % N;
int y= rnd / N;
```

That's it. No need for that awkward `if` contraption, whatsoever.

Comment: first coordinate and last coordinate are taken, that's way I add 2 there

Comment: awkward conditions are there because these coordinates are used with `vector<string>`, so v[y][x]